# Disable Column header from dragging, Tableview , Javafx

Tags: css, javafx, tableview

I want to disable all the features of table-view of JavaFX 8.0. I have disabled column sorting but i can't disable column header dragg and drop and its CSS.

Comment: Till now i have diable coloumn header unchanged by using this code.

Comment: Table.getColumns().addListener(new ListChangeListener<Object>() {
          public boolean suspended;

          @Override
          public void onChanged(Change change) {
              change.next();
              if (change.wasReplaced() && !suspended) {
                  this.suspended = true;
                  Table.getColumns().setAll(columns);
                  this.suspended = false;
              }
          }
      });